# Finding the term at which PI has specific value

Tags: java

I'm a bit stuck calculating the value of π from the infinite series:

**π = 4 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9 – 4/11 + ...**

The problem have to solve is "*Print a table that shows the value of π approximated by computing the first 200,000 terms of this series. How many terms do you have to use before you first get a value that begins with 3.14159?*"

I'm not sure if the condition that I'm using for finding this term is correct. Can someone tell me if it's right or not and if not what's the correct way to do this? I suspect it pertains to how Java rounds numbers.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double result = 0;
        int j = 1;
        int k = 1; //controls the if part for finding the term
        int term = 0; //variable for term that we're looking for

        for (int i = 1; i <= 200000; i += 1) {

            if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                result += (double) 4 / j; //positive part
                j += 2;
            }
            else {
                result -= (double) 4 / j; //negative part
                j += 2;
            }

            if (k != 0) {

                /* Attempts to detect when result == 3.14159 */

                if (result > 3.14158 && result < 3.14160) { 
                    term = i;
                    k = 0;
                }
            }

            System.out.printf("%f\n", result);
        }

        System.out.println("Term at which pi has value 3.14159: " + term);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, let me compliment you on asking a very clear and focused question and for posting neatly formatted code to inform whatever answers may be forthcoming.

Comment: I suspect it's related to how floating point numbers are stored internally, but I will look into this. BTW: Do you know C, and if so, have you tried porting it as directly as possible to the C Language to see if you get a similar result or not?

Comment: @clearlight it's nothing related to floating point storage - it's just that the range tests the OP has tried are incorrect.

Comment: @clearlight Thank you. I don't know the C, but it's as Alnitak said, the range was not correct. Thank you both for answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check is the number *begins* with 3.14159, you need to check for values *great than or equal to* that value, and *less than* 3.14160:

```
if (result >= 3.14159 && result < 3.14160) {
    ..
}
```

With that change I get a value for `term` of 136121, which I've verified elsewhere is the expected answer.

There's no need for any multiplication and rounding operations on the result because the range of precision required (six decimal digits) is far less than that provided by a Java `double`.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

The Java `Math` class is your friend. Documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

I would be inclined to do the test using `Math.floor(result * 100000) == 314159)`

You may also want to include `i` in your results so you can easily check your answer against the table.

Finally, I would use a `boolean` rather than an `int` for the test.

Comment: `Math.floor(result * 100000) == 3.14159` can never ever be true.

Comment: D'oh! Fixing that now

Comment: This is over complicated IMHO - a simple 2 character change of the first expression in the OP's code from `result > 3.14158` to `result >= 3.14159` fixes their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I incorporated @Alnitak's suggestion into code to give you some other ideas how you might optimize it and insights into how the language can be used. I tweaked it a little to iterate an order of magnitude more times and produce one more decimal place of precision. But the limit you're going to bump into with the IEEE 754 floating point math used by most languages is how floating point numbers are represented internally. Many numbers are actually 'not a number', e.g. impossible to represent. So there is rounding. I'm sure NASA has ways around this :-) I'm no mathematician but there are probably papers around that discuss techniques for achieving more precision, outside the scope of your question.

```
public class Main {

    private final static int MAX_LOOP = 2000000;    
    private static int i = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double j = 1.0, result = 0.0;

        for ( ; i < MAX_LOOP; i++, j += 2.0) {

            if ((i % 2) != 0) 
                result += 4.0 / j;
            else
                result -= 4.0 / j;

            if (result >= 3.141592 && result < 3.141593)
                break;

            System.out.println(result);
        }

        if (i < MAX_LOOP)
            System.out.println("Term at which pi has value 3.141592..." + result + " = " + i);
        else
            System.out.println("Couldn't find pi using series with maximum iterations = " + MAX_LOOP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this answer, I hope researching all this was beneficial for you as well :) . I'll do some research about numbers representation. I'm glad I asked this question because of your answers I see that there's so much to learn beside the syntax to be really good at programming which makes things even more interesting and motivating. Thank you one more time :)

Comment: Yeah, I enjoy passing along tricks of the trade. Didn't take long. Thanks for the good attitude.

Comment: :) , I hope I'll be able to pass along some tricks as well later on. You're welcome :)